I want to use mod_timer to timer for 10 milliseconds, but the result is always 20 milliseconds
my driver test code,I want to use mod_timer to timer for 10 milliseconds, but the result is always 20 milliseconds. what's wrong with it? ..
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

static struct timer_list my_timer;

void my_timer_callback(struct timer_list *timer)
{
    printk("my_timer_callback called (%lu).\n", jiffies);

    mod_timer(&my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(10));
}

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    printk("Timer module loaded\n");

    timer_setup(&my_timer, my_timer_callback, 0);

    mod_timer(&my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(10));

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    printk("Timer module unloaded\n");

    del_timer(&my_timer);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("developer@kk.com");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_IMPORT_NS(VFS_internal_I_am_really_a_filesystem_and_am_NOT_a_driver);

dmesg result:
[   70.391971] my_timer_callback called (4294944328).
[   70.411947] my_timer_callback called (4294944330).
[   70.431944] my_timer_callback called (4294944332).
[   70.451961] my_timer_callback called (4294944334).

kernel version: 5.10
.config：
CONFIG_HZ=100

What is the value of HZ?

the value of HZ is 100

./sound/isa/sb/sb8_midi.c:      mod_timer(&chip->midi_timer, 1 + jiffies); ./sound/isa/sb/sb8_midi.c:                      mod_timer(&chip->midi_timer, 1 + jiffies); ./sound/isa/sb/emu8000_pcm.c:   mod_timer(&rec->timer, jiffies + 1); ./sound/isa/sb/emu8000_pcm.c:           mod_timer(&rec->timer, jiffies + 1); 
kernel code also use jiffies

Isn't jiffies a u64 i.e. unsigned?

Is there a relationship with unsigned? It seems to be related to unsigned.

This question is similar to: Reliability of Linux kernel add_timer at resolution of one jiffy?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See mod_timer issue with linux kernel 4.18 for a possible workaround.

What happens if you replace mod_timer(&my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(10)); with mod_timer(&my_timer, my_timer.expires + msecs_to_jiffies(10)); in my_timer_callback()?

@AllanWind No, jiffies is a volatile unsigned long. get_jiffies_64() returns a u64.

@IanAbbott
The second time (callback) and subsequent timers seem to be working normally, why is that? Why didn't they work before?
[   71.831990] my_timer_callback called (4294944472).
[   71.841988] my_timer_callback called (4294944473).
[   71.851989] my_timer_callback called (4294944474).```

Can you print both timer->expires (or my_timer.expires since it is the same thing) and jiffies in the callback to check for discrepancies?

My point is that you print the value as signed.

@AllanWind It has been modified to %lu.

@IanAbbott It's the result of print both .
[   32.651901] my_timer_callback called (4294940554). [   32.651922] my_timer.expires=4294940553 [   32.661892] my_timer_callback called (4294940555). [   32.661911] my_timer.expires=4294940554 [   32.671892] my_timer_callback called (4294940556). [   32.671906] my_timer.expires=4294940555 [   32.681892] my_timer_callback called (4294940557). [   32.681907] my_timer.expires=4294940556 

So it looks like the callback is being called 1 jiffy after the expiry time. (A jiffy is 10 ms in your case).

@IanAbbott There are some comments in kernel/time/timer.c. There seems to be some correlation, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.
When i try to set timer form 10ms to 1000ms， my callback always comes 960ms or 1040ms  later. The drift(80ms)  is the Granularity  of level 1.
 * Level Offset  Granularity            Range
 *  0    0         10 ms               0 ms -        630 ms
 *  1   64         80 ms             640 ms -       5110 ms (640ms - ~5s)```

As experienced by OP, and as noted in this email message, it is possible that there may be a one-jiffy latency when invoking the timer expiry functions due to some CPUs reading the old jiffies value while another one is updating it.
Since OP's timer callback function adds a relative amount to jiffies to set the next expiry time, the time between callbacks may be one jiffy longer than required. This could be mitigated by setting the next expiry time to be relative to the previous expiry time. If the one-jiffy latency is consistent, then all the callback functions will run one-jiffy late. However, it is possible that some of the callback functions will run on time and some of them will run late, which may be undesirable.
If the use case requires more precise timing, it would be better to use the hrtimer API, as shown in a modified version of OP's code below:
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/hrtimer.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

static struct hrtimer my_timer;

static enum hrtimer_restart my_timer_callback(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
    s64 now = ktime_to_ns(hrtimer_cb_get_time(timer));
    s64 expires = ktime_to_ns(hrtimer_get_softexpires(timer));
    s64 diff = now - expires;

    printk("my_timer_callback called (now %lld, expired %lld, diff %lld).\n",
           now, expires, diff);

    hrtimer_add_expires_ns(timer, 10 * NSEC_PER_MSEC);
    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    printk("Timer module loaded\n");

    hrtimer_init(&my_timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);
    my_timer.function = my_timer_callback;

    hrtimer_start(&my_timer,
                  ktime_add_ms(hrtimer_cb_get_time(&my_timer), 10),
                  HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    printk("Timer module unloaded\n");

    hrtimer_cancel(&my_timer);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("developer@kk.com");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_IMPORT_NS(VFS_internal_I_am_really_a_filesystem_and_am_NOT_a_driver);

Example dmesg output from the module is shown below:
[ 7119.967286] my_timer_callback called (now 7119822903369, expired 7119822900229, diff 3140).
[ 7119.977294] my_timer_callback called (now 7119832911804, expired 7119832900229, diff 11575).
[ 7119.987347] my_timer_callback called (now 7119842964493, expired 7119842900229, diff 64264).
[ 7119.997286] my_timer_callback called (now 7119852903102, expired 7119852900229, diff 2873).
[ 7120.007348] my_timer_callback called (now 7119862964879, expired 7119862900229, diff 64650).
[ 7120.017348] my_timer_callback called (now 7119872964924, expired 7119872900229, diff 64695).
[ 7120.027347] my_timer_callback called (now 7119882964377, expired 7119882900229, diff 64148).
[ 7120.037333] my_timer_callback called (now 7119892950004, expired 7119892900229, diff 49775).
[ 7120.047348] my_timer_callback called (now 7119902964627, expired 7119902900229, diff 64398).
[ 7120.057348] my_timer_callback called (now 7119912964748, expired 7119912900229, diff 64519).
[ 7120.067337] my_timer_callback called (now 7119922952994, expired 7119922900229, diff 52765).
[ 7120.077350] my_timer_callback called (now 7119932966586, expired 7119932900229, diff 66357).
[ 7120.087348] my_timer_callback called (now 7119942964245, expired 7119942900229, diff 64016).
[ 7120.097334] my_timer_callback called (now 7119952950074, expired 7119952900229, diff 49845).
[ 7120.107351] my_timer_callback called (now 7119962966616, expired 7119962900229, diff 66387).

